# How can I reset my template with onchange event on angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a vertical navigation bar on the left side of my Angular app. The right side is for my content.

There are two select dropdown menüs in my Angular app. One of them is filled with our customers by calling web service method on the first loading of the app.

```
<select name="customer" id="customer" class="form-control" (change)="onCustomerChange(customerSelect.value)" [(ngModel)]="customerID" #customerSelect ngModel>
   <option *ngFor="let customer of customerlist" [value]="customer.CrmID">{{ customer.customername }}</option>
</select>
```

When I select a customer then another web service method is called. So the second dropdown is filled with the customers' contracts.

```
<select name="contract" id="contract" class="form-control" (change)="onContractChange(customerID, contractSelect.value)" #contractSelect ngModel>
   <option *ngFor="let contract of contractlist" [value]="contract.contractID">{{ contract.contractID }}</option>
</select>
```

When I select a contract then some options of the contract are appeared in horizontal nav in the content area on the right side.

Finally I select an option on this horizontal nav, so that I get the real content in the content area under the horizontal nav.

My target is: I need to reset or empty or hide my this real content if I 
1-) change the customer (first dropdown)
or 
2-) change the contract (second dropdown)
or 
3-) select an another option on horizontal nav in the content area on the right side.

I can hide the content by using Subject variable in a service.

```
private valueChanged = new Subject<boolean>();
```

I subscribe this Observable valueChanged in the component ngOnInit() of the real content.

```
showContentDiv: boolean;

ngOnInit(){
  this.myService.valueChanged.subscribe(
     (value: boolean) => {
       this.showContentDiv = value;
     }
  );
}
```

I use this boolean variable in my div with ngIf for showing or hiding the real content.

```
<div *ngIf="showContentDiv">
```

That works. But if I choose a contract (second dropdown) I mean when I want to show the content again with the true value of showContentDiv variable, div shows me the content of the last contract and I get an error about router-outlet. Because first it doesn't replace the content with the new one. Second the content template is generated in router-outlet. When I hide and then show it again it gives me error somehow.

How can I reset or empty my div content when I change any dropdown menu option? Or is my approach actually wrong for this case?

Could anyone please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: I'll help but I read through and I think you need to replicate this in StackBlitz for both of our sanity. Very simply, create the dropdowns with demo content and setup your Subject boolean. Also perhaps clarify and format your question.

Comment: Thank you Ben. But it's too complex to put all these codes in StackBlitz again. But I edited my question a little bit. What do you need more for understanding the problem?